# Qt Creator can't find library

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I'm using ubuntu(32 bit) on virtualbox. I am trying to add a the rtlsdr library but Qt creator can't find the rtlsdr library.
The library is located in /usr/local/lib/librtlsdr.so and I have tried adding the following to my .pro file

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lrtlsdr

INCLUDEPATH +=usr/local/lib
```

But I get the following error:

```
/home/luis/qt-bbb/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/luis/qt-bbb/tslib/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qt-arm/lib -o qt-test main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o -L/home/luis/qt-bbb/tslib/lib -L/opt/qt-arm/lib -L/home/luis/qt-arm/rtl-sdr/build/src/ -lrtlsdr -lQtGui -L/opt/qt-arm/lib -L/home/luis/qt-bbb/tslib/lib -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread

/home/luis/qt-bbb/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: *skipping incompatible /home/luis/qt-arm/rtl-sdr/build/src//librtlsdr.so when searching for -lrtlsdr*

/home/luis/qt-bbb/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: *skipping incompatible /home/luis/qt-arm/rtl-sdr/build/src//librtlsdr.a when searching for -lrtlsdr*

Makefile:105: recipe for target 'qt-test' failed

/home/luis/qt-bbb/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lrtlsdr

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [qt-test] Error 1
```

I'm using ubuntu 32bit to cross compile for my beaglebone running debian. Deploying on my beaglebone works ok and I verified the libraries are 32 bit so I don't know why it can't find them or why it's giving me “skipping incompatible” message. I also tried adding them by right clicking on the .pro->add library but still can't find them.

Comment: 1) The include path probably wasn't supposed to end in `/lib`, it should end in `/include`. 2) That same path should be absolute, nor relative. 3) Maybe your compiler is finding the ARM version and not the x86 version.

Comment: ``skipping incompatible`` tells you the library cannot be linked. Probably compiled with the wrong compiler?

Comment: Ok i figured out my problem, the library was built for x86 and not arm. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

`skipping incompatible` tells you the library cannot be linked. Probably compiled with the wrong compiler?
                    – Sebastian Lange

Ok i figured out my problem, the library was built for x86 and not arm. Thanks for the hints! – luismbedder